# Can't pass variable to value for Paypal Smart Button api

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I am trying to integrate the smart button api for paypal on my website. This is the code:

```
 paypal.Buttons({
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
  // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
  return actions.order.create({
    purchase_units: [{
      amount: {
        value: '10'
      }
    }]
  });
}
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I have my price variable like this:

```
var price = '100'
```

I have tried adding price instead of the '100' but I keep getting the uncaught reference error telling me that it has not been defined yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure it's defined in a sufficiently-global scope before the PayPal button executes.

If it is defined in a different function, not before the button is clicked, you will receive that error.

A quick fix would be to set `window.myPrice = '100';` , and then reference `value: window.myPrice` from your button

Of course, there are cleaner non-global-variable ways to do this.